# некорректная работа обработчика onClick для элементов TListBox (на андроид)

Tags: c++, c++builder, radstudio, android-on-click

Создал элемент (item) в Listbox.
Назначил ему обработчик `onClick`.
в обработчике сделал создание файла .txt с названием этого же самого элемента.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::ListBoxItem2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
ListBox1->Items->SaveToFile("(ListBox1->Items->Strings[ListBox1->ItemIndex])+".txt");
}
```

При компиляции под win32 все работает отлично. НО при компиляции под android при первом нажатии на элемент(item) вылетает вот такая ошибка (фото): 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, если я нажимаю еще следующие разы (причем любой из элементов этого listBox'а) все обработчики работают нормально (включая этот). Почему так? Как это исправить?

Comment: А разве это выражение компилируется  "(ListBox1->Items->Strings[ListBox1->ItemIndex])+".txt"? В нем нечетное число апострофов.

Comment: Четное же, все правильно. Этим я указывают название файла.

Comment: И где четное? Я насчитал три апострофа.

Comment: Ой. Это ошибка при копировании кода на сайт